# Javascript: Classes changes not rerendering

Tags: javascript, react-native, mapbox

I am trying to update my marker's coordinates on a map on React Native using hooks but I am not familiar with Java script and how they work. The coordinates are updated but does not reflect on the map (marker does not move to new coordinate) unless I exit and reenter the screen, but I want it to update automatically when I set a new coordinate. I have tried to use render() but it did not work due to some error (Functions are not valid as a React child). Is there a way to force render or an alternative to hooks for React Native that can be used for this case?

The marker x,y coordinates can be set using setxCord and setyCord

```js
      <MapboxGL.MarkerView coordinate={[xCord, yCord]} anchor={{x: 0, y: 0}} draggable={false}>
```

I have tried doing this

```js
// to update new position for marker
export class Position {
  constructor(x,y) {
    this.x = 5;
    this.y = 5;
  }
  getX() {
    return this.x;
  }

  setX(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  getY() {
    return this.y;
  }

  setY(y) {
    this.y = y;
  }

  setCoordinates(x,y) {
    var dx = x * 0.12 * 6.24 / 7.8 + 1.96;
    var dy = y * 0.12 * 9.55 / 12 + 0.35;
    this.x = dx;
    this.y = dy;
  }
}

const createScanHandler = () => {
  console.log(position);
  position.setCoordinates(32.5, 67.5);
}

let position = new Position();
```

I have also attempted to use .bind() but it did not work.
I also researched about using componentDidMount to update the coordinates but I cannot figure out how to use it, as I am not familiar with React and JS.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show where your `useState` call is? You have to set the state for react to update

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a useState call since my use case do not allow for the use of hook. What I have is a class where I can modify the coordinates using a function. However even though console log shows me the correct value, it is not updating in a <Text> </Text> enclosure. I am looking for a way to update not only in console log but also in the <Text> </Text> view. I hope this make sense.

Comment: Then show your `setState`

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your coordinates in:

```
const [coordinate, setCoordinate] = React.useState(/* here you object or array */);
```

If you see link [React lifecycle methods](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/). You see what render() called after changing props and state.

[Also see official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Using hook is what I would like to do however my problem is that the function that I want to modify the hook is outside of my main function due to how my code is structured. This means my function to set coordinate cannot access the hook. So I am looking for alternative method for a global hook or something like a variable tracker where a change in value will allow me to modify my state.

Comment: Pass function for set State like a props in to another component or class or object or function. And inside call them (setState function). Check this small [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-nobel-i92h5?)